# Code is getting stuck somewhere in a succession of for-loops and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, for-loop

EDIT - I changed the code to correctly declare variables below but nothing seems to have changed

I've written code using a for-loop that has to satisfy a number of criteria before executing what's within it. The problem is that, somewhere along the way, the code is getting stuck inside one of the loops, causing the computer to crash.

I've tried breaking the loop but this doesn't seem to help.

```
function compareKeypoints(varifiedKeypoints) {

  outer_loop: for (i = 0; i < varifiedKeypoints.length; i++) {

    let initialKeypoint = varifiedKeypoints[i];

    for (j = 0; j < varifiedKeypoints.length; j++) {

      let comparisonKeypoint = varifiedKeypoints[j];

      if (initialKeypoint.part != comparisonKeypoint.part) {

        if (Math.abs(comparisonKeypoint.position.x - initialKeypoint.position.x) <= 20
        && Math.abs(comparisonKeypoint.position.y - initialKeypoint.position.y) <= 20) {

          if (keypointsCompatible(initialKeypoint.part, comparisonKeypoint.part)) {

            console.log("Activating part: " + initialKeypoint.part);
            console.log("Activated part: " + comparisonKeypoint.part);

            let keypointPair = {
              point_1: initialKeypoint.part,
              point_2: comparisonKeypoint.part
            }

            console.log("Pushing parts!");
            activeParts.push(keypointPair);

            console.log("breaking loop!");
            break outer_loop;

            console.log("Loop NOT broken!!");

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (activeParts.length > 0) {
    console.log(activeParts);
  }
}

function keypointsCompatible(keypoint_1, keypoint_2) {

  var outcome = true;

  if (activeParts.length > 0) {

    compatibility_loop: for (i = 0; i < activeParts.length; i++) {

      if (Object.values(activeParts[i]).includes(keypoint_1) && Object.values(activeParts[i]).includes(keypoint_2)) {

        console.log(keypoint_1 + " and " + keypoint_2 + " are not compatible because they already exist as " + activeParts[i].point_1 + " and " + activeParts[i].point_2 + " respectively");

        outcome = false;

        break compatibility_loop;

        console.log("Compatibility NOT broken!!");
      }
    }
  }

  console.log("Compatibility outcome is " + outcome);
  return outcome;
}
```

The code is suppose to take two values in the same array and compare them. If a number of conditions are met, including if they're a certain distance apart from one another, they will be pushed into a secondary array. If the values already appear in the secondary array, which the keypointCompatible function is suppose to determine, the loop should either continue looking for other candidates or stop before being called again. For some reason, however, the code is getting stuck within the keypointCompatible function when it detects that the values have already appeared in the secondary array and the console will repeatedly print "Compatibility is false" until the browser crashes.

Comment: Can you explain the following two lines : 
```
break compatibility_loop;

console.log("Compatibility NOT broke!!");
```
The latter is redundant, unless I am missing something?

Comment: You should correctly declare your variables with `let, var, const`

Comment: Just as side note: your main loops makes redundant computation.

The inner loop should start at ``` j=i+1```
This will save a lot of time for large numbers

And ```activeParts``` IS NOT DEFINED. Please provide more info.

Comment: what does the console prints 'Compatibility outcome is false' or 'Compatibility is false'?

Comment: Please print the value of  ```varifiedKeypoints.length```

Comment: @Mulli "Compatibility NOT broke!!" was just a way for me to see if the break didn't work. Also, activeParts is just and empty secondary array.

Comment: @user2724072 Did you solve the problem by now? did you see my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Working Solution

Use `let` or `const` instead of `var` or nothing.  Your issue may be related to closures and variables reused between loops.  Make sure you use `let` or `const` in your loops too. `for (let i=0)`.

When you use `let` or `const`, the runtime will create a new instance every time the block or loop iterates.  However, using `var` will reuse the internal allocation.

So what happens with the standard `var` is the multiple closures or loops each use the same instance of the variable.

Unless you want the `var` behavior, always use `let` or `const`.

---

## Another Solution

Put a newline after the label `compatibility_loop`

## Still Another Solution

The first function is pushing into `activeParts`.  The second function is looping `activeParts`. This can go on forever, or longer than expected.  Pushing into the array could possibly make the loop limit never reached.
Put a log on the length of `activeParts` in the second function to see if it is growing out of control.

Comment: Hey Steven if you scroll down it's there

Comment: Hey Steven, thanks for the response. Can you expand on the first solution? What do you mean exactly by "related"? The compareKeypoints function is only called once the varifiedKeypoints have been finalized and the function only relies on what's been given to it as a parameter to work. I'm not removing anything from varifiedKeypoints to push into activeParts.

Comment: The was before I saw second function.  I also don't see where `activeParts` or `varifiedKeypoints` is defined.  I will update solution.

Comment: Hey Steven, it seems like declaring the variables in the for loop did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2724072 Nice.  I will update solution with reason why it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be OK if `varifiedKeypoints.length` has reasonable value. And all internal variables are declared properly!

You have two loops (this inner can start at `j=i+1` to save time and multiple calculations) with few conditions inside.

```
function compareKeypoints(varifiedKeypoints) {

  outer_loop: for (let i = 0; i < varifiedKeypoints.length; i++) {

    let initialKeypoint = varifiedKeypoints[i];

    for (let j = i+1; j < varifiedKeypoints.length; j++) {

      let comparisonKeypoint = varifiedKeypoints[j];
```